# I want to sort the given list which start from small character?

Tags: python, list, sorting

`given list`

```
 ["Ram", "vikram", "Avneet", "navneet", "ghazala", "Komal", "sita", "aman", "Babar"]
```

`output (this is expected output)`

```
['aman', 'ghazala', 'navneet', 'sita', 'vikram', 'Avneet', 'Babar', 'Komal', 'Ram']
```

`how I get this answer`

```
list2 = sorted(list1)
for i in list2:
    if i.istitle():
        int = list2.index(i)
        
for i in range(int+1):
    appended = list2[0]
    list2.remove(appended)
    list2.append(appended)
    
print(list2)
```

> but I am using 2 for loop which is to bad coding please provide another solution with shorter, clearner and more readable

I want to sort the list with all items starting from small letter first in this given list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a lambda for the `key` argument that first checks if the string `.istitle` (i.e. starts with a capital letter), then after that just sorts alphabetically.

```
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda i: (i.istitle(), i))
['aman', 'ghazala', 'navneet', 'sita', 'vikram', 'Avneet', 'Babar', 'Komal', 'Ram']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you please explain me what is happening inside key argument while sorting , how it working I unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict and store two lists there!

```py
sorting = {
    'lowercase':[],
    'uppercase':[]
}
for value in original_list:
    if value.istitle():
        sorting['uppercase'].append(value)
    else:
        sorting['lowercase'].append(value)

#extend
result = sorted(sorting['lowercase']) + sorted(sorting['uppercase'])
```

Comment: Forget it. Cory Kramer's answer is more pythonic :)